# GPG Error on debian wheezy when execute 'sudo apt-get update'

Tags: debian, gnupg

I have installed Debian wheezy. Then I want to set apt source, just like below:

```
deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib 
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib 

deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main contrib 
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main contrib
```

Then I execute the command 'sudo apt-get update', I get the error message:

```
Get:1 http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates Release.gpg
Get:2 http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates Release   
Ign http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates Release       
E: GPG error: http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates Release: The following signatures were invalid: NODATA 1 NODATA 2
```

My apt-key list output is:

```
/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d//debian-archive-squeeze-automatic.gpg
------------------------------------------------------------
pub   4096R/473041FA 2010-08-27 [expires: 2018-03-05]
uid                  Debian Archive Automatic Signing Key (6.0/squeeze) <ftpmaster@debian.org>

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d//debian-archive-squeeze-stable.gpg
---------------------------------------------------------
pub   4096R/B98321F9 2010-08-07 [expires: 2017-08-05]
uid                  Squeeze Stable Release Key <debian-release@lists.debian.org>

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d//debian-archive-wheezy-automatic.gpg
-----------------------------------------------------------
pub   4096R/46925553 2012-04-27 [expires: 2020-04-25]
uid                  Debian Archive Automatic Signing Key (7.0/wheezy) <ftpmaster@debian.org>

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d//debian-archive-wheezy-stable.gpg
--------------------------------------------------------
pub   4096R/65FFB764 2012-05-08 [expires: 2019-05-07]
uid                  Wheezy Stable Release Key <debian-release@lists.debian.org>
```

How I can solve the GPG error?